# Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: cefsharp

We have installed CerfSharp using the NuGet Pakage Manager and created a class library which loads a ChromiumWebBrowser, it works fine on VisualStudio-2019,
When we deployed the class library(DLL) into target location along with required cefsharp supported files as mentioned the readme.txt, which throws following exception

Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
Stack Trace:    at CefSharp.Cef.get_IsInitialized()

could anyone help us on this issue?

Added following cefsharp supported files in the target deployment location:

- CEF core library.

  - libcef.dll
- Crash reporting library.

  - chrome_elf.dll
- Unicode support data.

  - icudtl.dat
- V8 snapshot data.

  - snapshot_blob.bin
  - v8_context_snapshot.bin

[System Info]:

CefSharp Version=91.1.230.0

OS: Windows 7 x64

Visual Studio Version:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.7.8
.NET Framework: 4.8

Thanks,

Comment: Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3758 please just ask your question once and wait for a reply.